# Recycle bin Script in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, recycle-bin

In my production server, somebody executed `rm -rf` and my important files are removed permanently. So, I thought of having a recycle bin, so if a user do `rm`the file will move to RecycleBin rather than deleting from server. And i've made the below script for it. But I'm getting some error while it executed.

`alias rm='/root/remove.sh'`

`#rm test_file`
Now below script will trigger when you type the `rm` command

`#!/bin/bash`
`dir=$(pwd)`
`mv $dir/$1 /root/Recyclebin`

when the above script is triggered i'm getting the following error.

`mv:cannot move '/root/test_file' to '/root/Recyclebin': Not a directory`

Now, please suggest is there anyother way to make a recycle bin concept other than this or please help to resolve the error. Thanks in advance.

I'm using CentOS 5.6

Comment: Does `/root/Recyclebin` even exist?

Comment: Try this : [shell script that move all of the files you delete into the .recyclebin directory](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2015/04/write-shell-script-that-move-all-of.html)

Answer (score 5):

Try This
At first create a folder named as MyTrash under /root ie: /root/MyTrash

Then open .bashrc file and write the below line at the bottom of the file.

`alias rm='mv -t /root/MyTrash/'`

Here `-t` means

```
-t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
       move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
```

update `.bashrc` file by running this command `source .bashrc`

Now if you delete any file using `rm` command that file will be moved to `/root/MyTrash` directory

Comment: how about mounted folders?